# Will a firewall block local TCP communication between processes?

Tags: windows, tcp, firewall

I am splitting an application into a tray application and a Windows Service and I want to use TCP to communicate between the two*. They will both be running on the same machine.

My question is do firewalls block TCP communication between applications running on the same machine? I want to know whether firewalls are something I need to worry about when testing.

(*note that I want to use TCP instead of named pipes for communication because the apps might one day run on separate computers but that will be far in the future)

Comment: Windows Firewall does not.  I don't know about third-party firewalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary objective of the firewall is to control the incoming and the outgoing network traffic! Firewall's are designed to work on IP or PORT basis.

So yes, it is 100% capable of blocking connection on same machine.(I guess you are using Class A IP [`127.x.y.x`] address used mainly for loopback testing and interprocess communication on the local computer).

Some firewall are preconfigured not to block local machine connection while other are configured to block them. But either way a firewall can be configured to allow/deny such connection.