# running client and server class on same machine but no connection?

Tags: java, sockets

i'm using textbook client and server classes on my laptop, but when i run both programs they don't seem to connect. i just open two command prompt windows compile and run the server on one and then compile the client on the other window. what am i doing wrong?

here is the server code

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DateServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date now = new Date();
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for a connection on port 7655.");
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(7655);
            Socket connectionSock = serverSock.accept();
            BufferedReader clientInput = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connectionSock.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream clientOutput = new DataOutputStream(
                    connectionSock.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Connection made, waiting for client " +
                    "to send their name.");
            String clientText = clientInput.readLine();
            String replyText = "Welcome, " + clientText +
                    ", Today is " + now.toString() + "\n";
            clientOutput.writeBytes(replyText);
            System.out.println("Sent: " + replyText);
            clientOutput.close();
            clientInput.close();
            connectionSock.close();
            serverSock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the client code:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DateClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String hostname = "localhost";
            int port = 7655;
            System.out.println("Connecting to server on port " + port);
            Socket connectionSock = new Socket(hostname, port);
            BufferedReader serverInput = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connectionSock.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream serverOutput = new DataOutputStream(
                    connectionSock.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Connection made, sending name.");
            serverOutput.writeBytes("Dusty Rhodes\n");
            System.out.println("Waiting for reply.");
            String serverData = serverInput.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + serverData);
            serverOutput.close();
            serverInput.close();
            connectionSock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: running properly on netbeans and also on cmd also

Comment: @swapnil7 did you use two different cmd screens?

Comment: yes i used two different cmd screens

Comment: You don't flush your output i.e. you don't ensure that the data is actually sent to the server. You rely on the fact that the data will be written directly to the server or underlying buffer will get flushed somehow - in your system this seems not to be the case. Another thing you should check is if there exists a firewall rule that blocks the connection.

Comment: @swapnil7 i tried changing ports...but still no connection. they seem to be running forever. any thoughts?

Comment: check after closing your firewall and anitvirus protection off

Comment: @swapnil7 if it is an internal connection should that matter?

Comment: yes it is 100% capable of blocking connection { resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302705/will-a-firewall-block-local-tcp-communication-between-processes }

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port number and see.Might be some other app is running on this port.There is no problem with your code.I can run it.

Comment: i tried changing ports...but still no connection. they seem to be running forever. any thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting any exception?.you should run the client program also not only compile.

Comment: @user2910237 no exceptions. just no response. swapnil7 thinks its my firewall.

Comment: When I tried to run your program for the first time firewall blocked and asked for access.